# USB-C/ Thunderbolt Connection Dropped When Laptop Fully Charged

Tags: power-management, laptop, lenovo, thunderbolt, usb-c

I'm running a Lenovo X1 Extreme on Ubuntu 18.04.02 LTS.

I have discovered that if I charge the laptop using USB-C then the laptop breaks the connection once or twice every 15 minutes or so.

The issue is very minor when charging only, but if it's receiving power from the dock it breaks the connection, resets the screens and has to restart all its USB devices again, rendering the dock effectively unusable.

For now the issue has been observed many times on the dock and also with a USB-C laptop charger plugged in alone. It seems to happen only when the battery gets to full charge, leading me to suspect the device is doing some type of power switch and losing the connection in the process.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Short answer:no. My 'workaround' has been to use the dock with additional power running to the laptop through the charger (somewhat defeating the point of USB-C!)


In that configuration, the issue almost never appears, with the exception of running graphics-intensive applications, particularly on one of the two monitors.


The issue I had above with the charger seems to be a red herring as I regularly use it with USB-C delivering power only and have no issues now.